# Change decimal separated time into HH:MM

Tags: r, time

So I just want to convert the time from for example 6.25 to 06:15, 6.50 to 06:30 or 6.75 to 06:45.

How can I do that in R?

Comment: If I'm following the pattern correctly, wouldn't 6.75, not 6.8, be equivalent to 6:45? i.e. 6:45 is 75% of the way from 6:00 to 7:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the function `hms::hms()` to change decimal time to formated. Like this:

```
library(hms)
#your decimal time 6.5 hours
hms(hours = 6.5)
# 06:30:00
```

Comment: Ok how is this working for a sequence of time. I get a messy output there.                                                                                                                 `time <- c(6.5, 8.3, 9.2)                                                                     hms(hours=time)                                                                     06:30:00.000000
08:18:00.000000
09:12:00.000000`

Comment: The results is a `difftime` vector always in seconds. You can convert to character or numeric values using coertion functions `as.*()`. For example:  `as.character(hms(hours=time))` returns `#[1] "06:30:00.000000" "08:18:00.000000" "09:12:00.000000"`